# Null ouput on the JSP page from Java class

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am getting a null output for the 3 variables on my JSP page. These are my files:

**index.jsp**

```
    <jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" class="user.CompileClass" />
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user"/>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="Result.jsp">
What's your name? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=uname SIZE=20><BR>
What's your e-mail address? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=mail SIZE=20><BR>
What's your age? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=age SIZE=4>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**CompileClass.java**

```
    package user;

public class CompileClass {
    public String uname;
    public String mail;
    public int age;


    public CompileClass(){
    }



    public void setUname( String name ) {
        uname = name;
    }
    public void setMail( String name ) {
        mail = name;
    }
    public void setAge( int num ) {
        age = num;
    }

     public String getUname() { 
        return uname;
    }

     public String getMail() { 
         return mail;
     }

     public int getAge() { 
         return age;
     }
/*public void main()
{


}*/
}
```

**Result.jsp**

```
    <jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" class="user.CompileClass" />

<html>

  <body>
   You entered:<BR>

Name: <%= user.getUname()  %><br/>
Email: <%= user.getMail() %><BR>
Age: <%= user.getAge() %><BR>
  </body>
</html>
```

The project containing these files in Eclipse is compiling and running successfully but when I am giving any input for **Name** **Email** and **Age** the ouput is **null**

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the bean properties during displaying the result page, not during displaying the start page (simply because there's nothing submitted then). Move

```
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user"/>
```

from `index.jsp` to `result.jsp`. Actually, the whole `<jsp:useBean>` on `index.jsp` is also pointless, you aren't using it anywhere there. You could just remove that line from `index.jsp`.

You also need to replace those old fashioned *scriptlets* by EL to get it to display the real bean properties.

```
Name: ${user.uname}<br/>
Email: ${user.mail}<br/>
Age: ${user.age}<br/>
```